# Duplicating a Jekyll site on Github repo deployed with Netlify

Tags: github, jekyll, netlify

Before I start - I'm a hobbyist so pardon if I botch some terminology.

I made a little website using a Jekyll theme, using front matter and edited what I needed to edit with VSCode. Repository was created on Github, and deployed on Netlify because that's what the theme readme instructed me to do. (offtopic question, what does it mean to deploy and why can't the site just be uploaded to Netlify and work, why does it have to be a repo and deployment).

So, with my website looking exactly as I want it on localhost, I can push all the changes and the website will go live on whatever.netlify.app

Now, on to my main issue. I want to make another website, very similar (but not identical) to the first one. There would be some changes in style and text, andthe name of course.

What is the correct way of doing this? Copy paste the local folder in a new repo, or clone somehow in Github?

And another off-topic question, I got an email from theme author that he updated the theme with some fixes, how do I apply the update? Because I made many changes to various scss, yml and md files all over the theme. Thanks!